# Google Api fails When Application Gateway is Enabled

Tags: c#, azure, google-api, azure-application-gateway

I have developed a google calendar sync from our application and everything is working fine until we enabled Application Gateway.

Below is the google api request to get access token

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=yyyyyyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=zzzzzzzzzzzzz&redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/Employee/GoogleAuth&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Reponse of above request is

```
requestUri":"/Employee/GoogleAuth?state=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&code=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
```

As per my research it is clear that with Application gateway enabled the above response fails under rule 93130

[image]

Since the response contains scope with google doamin(https://www.googleapis.com/) app gateway will throw error and the actual api call will result in 403 forbidden error.

Disable this rule in Application Gateway will make the api call success. But here I am looking for some suggestion to make api call working without disabling the rule in application Gateway.Is there a way to exclude few domains?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isnt an option to exclude domains currently. Your current course of action is to disable the rule. Alternatively you could add the scope paramenter to exclusion list in which case WAF would not evaluate the contents of the parameter.

Comment: Got it.Thanks for your reply.